# How to Update Schema in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one JSON dataset where I have the below schema

```
myjsondata = spark.read.json("/FileStore/tables/customer.json")

myjsondata.printSchema()
```

[image]

I want to update this schema so I used the below command

```
myjsondataDDL="address_id INT,birth_country String,birthdate date,customer_id INT,demographics STRUCT<buy_potential: string,credit_rating: string,education_status: string,income_range: array<>,purchase_estimate:INT,vehicle_count: INT>,email_address: string,firstname: string,gender: string,is_preffered_customer: string,lastname: string,salutation: string"
```

I am not able to update schema here. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this schema below. Your schema has some syntax errors, with some unneeded colons (colons are only needed for field names inside struct type) and missing array type.

```
myjsondataDDL = """
    address_id INT,
    birth_country String,
    birthdate date,
    customer_id INT,
    demographics STRUCT<buy_potential: string, credit_rating: string, education_status: string, income_range: array<int>, purchase_estimate:INT, vehicle_count: INT>,
    email_address string,
    firstname string,
    gender string,
    is_preffered_customer string,
    lastname string,
    salutation string
"""
myjsondata = spark.read.schema(myjsondataDDL).json('absolute path of file')
```